# PLNotifyImagePickerOfImageAvailability crash

Tags: ios, swift

UIImagePickerController crash on image capture.

Refer to logs captured by crashlytics:

*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x182ec81c0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18190055c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x182da979c -[__NSCFNumber hash]
3  PhotoLibrary                   0x18f9e5974 __CreateInfoForImage
4  PhotoLibrary                   0x18f9e564c PLNotifyImagePickerOfImageAvailability
5  CameraUI                       0x198443d14 -[CAMImagePickerCameraViewController _handleCapturedImagePickerPhotoWithCropOverlayOutput:]
6  CameraUI                       0x198443628 -[CAMImagePickerCameraViewController cropOverlayWasOKed:]
7  UIKit                          0x188d467b0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
8  UIKit                          0x188d46730 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
9  UIKit                          0x188d30be4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
10 UIKit                          0x188d4601c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
11 UIKit                          0x188d45b44 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
12 UIKit                          0x188d40d8c -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
13 UIKit                          0x188d11858 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
14 UIKit                          0x1894fecb8 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
15 UIKit                          0x1894f8720 __handleEventQueue
16 CoreFoundation                 0x182e76278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
17 CoreFoundation                 0x182e75bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
18 CoreFoundation                 0x182e737c0 __CFRunLoopRun
19 CoreFoundation                 0x182da2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
20 GraphicsServices               0x184825198 GSEventRunModal
21 UIKit                          0x188d7c628 -[UIApplication _run]
22 UIKit                          0x188d77360 UIApplicationMain
23 newbe                          0x1002a2a60 main (AppDelegate.swift:22)
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x181d845b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: Did you find a way how to fix it?

Comment: Any update on this?